# how do i select an entire url address in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

in contenteditable, links don't work, so i'm thinking the best solution is to at least be able to select an entire url with one click or two clicks when the cursor is in any part of the url, then right-click and go to the site. is there a javascript solution to this, something similar to android phone's long-press-select and paste?

`<div contenteditable="true">some text here, then the complete url https://gizmodo.com/e-ink-kaleido-3-gallery-3-foldable-color-e-readers-1848842166 but i just want to select the url with one or two clicks, how? </div>`

contenteditable:

some text here, then the complete url https://gizmodo.com/e-ink-kaleido-3-gallery-3-foldable-color-e-readers-1848842166 but i just want to select the url with one or two clicks, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the url strings with `anchor tags` and attach an `onclick` listener to navigate to the url on click:

```js
text.innerHTML = text.textContent.replace(/https*:\/\/[^\s]+/gmi, (match) => `<a style="cursor:pointer" href="${match}">${match}</a>`);

[...text.children].forEach(a => a.onclick = (e) => window.open(a.href))

text.onblur = e => {
e.target.innerHTML = e.target.textContent.replace(/https*:\/\/[^\s]+/gmi, (match) => `<a style="cursor:pointer" href="${match}">${match}</a>`);
[...text.children].forEach(a => a.onclick = (e) => window.open(a.href))
}
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">some text here, then the complete url https://gizmodo.com/e-ink-kaleido-3-gallery-3-foldable-color-e-readers-1848842166 i just want to select the url with one or two clicks, how? Another url here: https://gizmodo.com/e-ink-kaleido-3-gallery-3-foldable-color-e-readers-1848842166
</div>
```

(*The navigation in the snippet iframe is prevented but it should work in a normal window*)

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work. once you add a link inside the contenteditable it's just plain text. is there a way to at least click on any part of the link to copy the address? thanks.

Comment: You could just add the same logic to an onblur event listener, so when you blur after typing it parses the urls again, I updated the example.

Comment: oh thank you so much Cesare -- this works beautifully.

Comment: hey Cesare -- is there a way to exclude image links? every time i insert/paste an image link it removes it. btw, i opted for the first code. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "exclude" ? You don't want that to be parsed as a link ?

Comment: right, i guess don't want to parse it as a link -- i just want to paste url images

Comment: How do you identify them ? They end in *.png *.jpg ? It's always a matter of building the right regexp,  if you know what to target, you can build your own regexps with a bit of pathience  here https://regex101.com/

Comment: yes i tried that site -- https://regex101.com/r/wJ6bD5/3 -- but it still removes image links, the url works, but if it's an image url it deletes when i save the webpage, the image is not there.  here's the code -- text.innerHTML = text.textContent.replace(/\bhttps?:\/\/(?!\S+(?:jpe?g|png|bmp|gif))\S+/gmi, (match) => `<a style="cursor:pointer" href="${match}">${match}</a>`);   [...text.children].forEach(a => a.onclick = (e) => window.open(a.href))  
--